# How to fetch values from dictionary within list python

Tags: python

How to assign key and values to different variables in the dictionary within the list. I'm using for loop but is there any better approach that I can assign and use the values globally.

```
data = [{'country':[1,'US']}]

for i in data:
    for j in i.items():
        type = j[0]
        rank = j[1][0]
        country = j[1][0]
print(type)
print(rank)
print(country)
```

Comment: Is there only ever going to be a single item in the list? What are you trying to do with the values you extract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your approach using for loop but you can do this to make it a little bit neater: (Also do not shadow the name "type")

```
data = [{'country': [1, 'US']}]

for i in data:
    for k, v in i.items():
        type_ = k
        rank, country = v

print(type_)
print(rank)
print(country)
```

Or :

```
data = [{'country': [1, 'US']}]

for i in data:
    for type_, (rank, country) in i.items():
        print(type_)
        print(rank)
        print(country)
```

If there is only one dictionary inside your list you can do this as well :

```
data = [{'country': [1, 'US']}]

type_, (rank, country) = next(iter((data[0].items())))

print(type_)
print(rank)
print(country)
```

Comment: If there are multiple dictionaries in list data = [{'country':[2,'US']},{'county':[1,'RS']}] then how to print max value of all dictionaries and also country name in that list for eg: 'US' here.

Comment: @swarna I think it's better to post a new question for this.

Comment: I posted  as new question